# Delphi 7 - How to fill a rounded rectangle with brush?

Tags: delphi, canvas, rounded-corners

I am trying to use Canvas to paint a Dialog-like form. I can put rounded borders in it and a rounded rectangle as a header/title. I want to fill only the title with brush.

[image: see form here]

However, I'm struggling to fill this title. When using `FillRect` all Form is repainted. Tried to search here, so if I missed, just point me where to go. Otherwise, how can I do it? Using Delphi 7, OnPaint event.

```
procedure TCustomDialog.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Rect: TRect;
  BorderColor: TColor;
  BrushColor: TColor;
begin
  // Rect for Form's borders;
  Rect.Left := 0;
  Rect.Top := 0;
  Rect.Right  := ClientWidth;
  Rect.Bottom := ClientHeight;

  BorderColor := HtmlToTColor('#ffffff');
  BrushColor := HtmlToTColor('#ffffff');

  // Here I set the colors of Canvas.Pen (border) and Canvas.Brush (Filling),
  // similar to Bootstrap themes/classes (Default, Success, Warning, Danger);
  case DialogType of
    dtInformation:
    begin
      BorderColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Pen_Information);
      BrushColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Brush_Information);
    end;

    dtSuccess:
    begin
      BorderColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Pen_Success);
      BrushColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Brush_Success);
    end;

    dtWarning:
    begin
      BorderColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Pen_Warning);
      BrushColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Brush_Warning);
    end;

    dtError:
    begin
      BorderColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Pen_Error);
      BrushColor := HtmlToTColor(Header_Color_Brush_Error);
    end;
  end;

  with Canvas do
  begin
    Pen.Color := BorderColor;
    Pen.Width := Form_Pen_Width;

    // Draw rounded borders for Form;
    RoundRect(1, 1, Rect.Right - 1, Rect.Bottom - 1, Form_Border_Radius - 1, Form_Border_Radius - 1);

    // Rect for Dialog's Header;
    Rect.Left := Component_Gutter;
    Rect.Top := Component_Gutter;
    Rect.Right  := ClientWidth - Component_Gutter;
    Rect.Bottom := Form_Header_Height;

    RoundRect(Component_Gutter, Component_Gutter, ClientWidth - Component_Gutter, Form_Header_Height,
  Form_Border_Radius - 2, Form_Border_Radius - 2);

    Brush.Color := BrushColor;
    FillRect(Rect);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your image link is broken. Please don't host images on external sites. StackOverflow has its own image hosting. Please upload your image to StackOverlow directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Edited.

Comment: In preparations to draw the rounded rectangle, define `Brush` to the color you want it to be filled with. From doc: *Use RoundRect to draw a rounded rectangle using Pen and fill it with Brush*. If I understand your code, move the `Brush.Color := BrushColor;` line before `RoundRect()` call and remove the `FillRect()` call.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks for comment. I've tried before this, however all form gets filled.

Comment: Tom is correct. F.i. `Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;` `Canvas.RoundRect(10, 10, 150, 50, 30, 10);` draws a filled round rect. Provide a [mcve] and we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have not seen your earlier code. Did you move the line I told you to, to just before `RoundRect(Component_Gutter ....)` and did you remove the `FillRect()` call as I told you? What is the result now? It cannot be the same as the problem you claim to have. Are you going to provide an MCVE, or are you just waiting for a miracle to happen.

Comment: @TomBrunberg It worked. See edit.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because it's inappropriate. If you'd like to share the answer you found, please do so properly using the space below for answers. Answering your own question is [acceptable here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but only if you do so properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you prepare to draw the rounded rectangle, define `Brush.Color` to have the color you want the rectangle to be filled with, before drawing.

The [Documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphi7/D7_DevelopersGuide.pdf) for Delphi 7 says:

> Rectangle
>   Draws a rectangle on the canvas with its upper left corner
>   at the point (X1, Y1) and its lower right corner at the point (X2,
>   Y2). Use Rectangle to draw a box using Pen and fill it using Brush.
>
> RoundRect
>   Draws a rectangle with rounded corners on the canvas.

From Delphi XE7 doc:

> Use RoundRect to draw a rounded rectangle using Pen and fill it with
>   Brush.

So, you need to define the colors for `Pen` and `Brush` before you call `RoundRect()`

The last block of your code should be in line with

```
  with Canvas do
  begin
    Pen.Color := BorderColor;
    Pen.Width := Form_Pen_Width;
    Brush.Color := BrushColor; // Add this line to control which fill color the form will have

    // Draw rounded borders for Form;
    RoundRect(1, 1, Rect.Right - 1, Rect.Bottom - 1, Form_Border_Radius - 1, Form_Border_Radius - 1);

    // Rect for Dialog's Header;
    Rect.Left := Component_Gutter;
    Rect.Top := Component_Gutter;
    Rect.Right  := ClientWidth - Component_Gutter;
    Rect.Bottom := Form_Header_Height;

    Brush.Color := clYellow;  // This line defines the fill color of the "header"
    RoundRect(Component_Gutter, Component_Gutter, ClientWidth - Component_Gutter, Form_Header_Height, Form_Border_Radius - 2, Form_Border_Radius - 2);

    Brush.Color := BrushColor; // Resets the brush color to the same as the form has
//    FillRect(Rect); Remove this line, as it overdraws the "header" incl. its border
  end;
```

And a sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To fill a non-rectangular shape, you can create an `HRGN` of the desired shape, such as with the Win32 [`CreateRoundRectRgn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183516.aspx) function, and then fill the Canvas using that `HRGN` with the Win32 [`FillRgn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162720.aspx) function.

Alternatively, after drawing solid borders around the desired area, use `TCanvas.FloodFill()` to fill it in.